# React key error although all elements have unique identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am getting used to React and I understand when using the map function each item needs to be assigned a unique key. I believe I am doing this correctly

```
    return (
     countries.map(country => {
        return <>
        <div key={country.name.common}>
            {country.name.common} <button onClick={() => setCountries([country])}>show</button>
        </div>
        </>
      })
   )
```

I still receive an error in the console saying:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

at CountryList.

at div.

Where CountryList being the file the code is extracted from. I have tried adding the same key to the button element and also tried giving the button element its own unique key.

[descriptive key error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaZaV.png)

countries is a call to "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all" api.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
         .then(response => setCountries(response.data))
  }, [])
```

```js
const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value)
    const filtered = countries.filter(country => country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value))
    setCountries(filtered)
  }
```

[console error message along with what the app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls7dk.png)

Comment: can you add how `countries` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key must be placed on the parent element that you are returning from the map function.
Since it's a fragment in this case, you can't directly assign a key to it, unless you use the actual [fragment component](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

```
// Can't assign a key
<></>
// Can assign a key
<React.Fragment key={...}></React.Fragment>
```

Then again, if you only have the `div` here, why do you need the fragment?
A shorter syntax of your code would look like this:

```
return (
   countries.map(country => (
      <div key={country.name.common}>
         {country.name.common}
         <button onClick={() => setCountries([country])}>show</button>
      </div>
   ))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<>` as a perent tag and add key in child `<div>` tag. remove `<></>` as you dont need this or use `Fragment` insted

```
  return countries.map(country => (
    <div key={country.name.common}>
      {country.name.common}
      <button onClick={() => setCountries([country])}>show</button>
    </div>
  ))
```

or

```
return countries.map(country => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={country.name.common}>
      <div>
        {country.name.common} <button onClick={() => setCountries([country])}>show</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank you, using Fragment fixed this error message!